# STEM Student Loan Forgiveness Question

Tags: united-states, student-loan

[Under Title 20 Chapter 28 Section 1078-11 of the U.S. Code](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/20/1078%E2%80%9311) there's a provision of student loan forgiveness for those working in a STEM field.

I contacted the Department of Education (which has student loan forgiveness [forms](https://studentloans.gov/myDirectLoan/formLibrary.action) for Public Sector workers and Teachers), and they referred me to my loan initiator ([Fedloan Servicing]) to obtain the appropriate documentation.  A Fedloan Servicing representative informed me that they didn't offer a STEM field forgiveness.

Has anyone had any success utilizing this method of loan forgiveness at all through Fedloan Servicing or some other loan initiator?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you working as a teacher?  If so, you might be eligible for the [Public Service Loan Forgiveness program](https://studentaid.ed.gov/sa/repay-loans/forgiveness-cancellation/public-service).  See [other questions on the PSLF](http://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=public+service+loan+forgiveness).

Comment: @BenMiller no unfortunately not :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did a bit more digging.  A closer look at the actual [US Code](http://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml;jsessionid=CD596C086DE76C3F09DF7F520AD5DD0A?req=granuleid%3AUSC-prelim-title20-chapter28&saved=L3ByZWxpbUB0aXRsZTIwL2NoYXB0ZXIyOC9zdWJjaGFwdGVyMS9wYXJ0QQ%3D%3D%7CZ3JhbnVsZWlkOlVTQy1wcmVsaW0tdGl0bGUyMC1jaGFwdGVyMjgtc3ViY2hhcHRlcjEtcGFydEE%3D%7C%7C%7C0%7Cfalse%7Cprelim&edition=prelim) shows that this is a provision under the Federal Family Education Loan Program which ended in January 2010 and it seems only those loans made under this program are eligible.